# Create unique instances of an object with a loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create 100 unique bank accounts.. all the names will be set to Person so I have used an ID to show they are different.

```
class Customer
{
    public static string name;
    public static int[] accounts = { };
    public static int id = 0;
    public static int balance = 100;
    public static double interest = balance * 1.05;

    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("Balance: £" + balance);
        Console.WriteLine("Balance after interest: £" + interest);
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + id);
    }

    public Customer()
    {
        name = "Person";
        balance = 100;
        id++;
    }
    public Customer(string _name, int _id, int _balance)
    {
        name = _name;
        id = _id;
        balance = _balance;
        id++;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Customer.id);
        Customer ash = new Customer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            Customer newPerson = new Customer();
            Console.WriteLine();
            newPerson.print(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can set the name for whoever has id 53 for example?
As I'm not sure if this is making 100 different instances or the same instance and just adding +1 to the id each time?

Any advice is great
Many thanks, I'm new to C# so just trying some basic stuff.

Comment: Well you're definitely creating 100 instances, but you're not retaining references to most of them. Perhaps you should be creating a `List<Customer>`?

Comment: Right, and also all members are `static`

Answer (score 1):

First off whenever you call `new Customer()` you create a new instance of `Cust0mer` which has nothing to do with any existing one. However as all your properties are `static` all your instances of the class share the same values for those properties instead of having their own. This means all your instances have the same name, ID and so on (anyway they are still *distinct instances*).

You can use the [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-overload which also returns the current index:

```
var instances = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select((x, i) => new Customer { ID = i });
```

This will create 100 instances of `Customer` with IDs from zero to 99. With this appraoch you won´t need a static variable to get to know how many instances you already created.

Another approach would be to hold this information directly within your class and assign it to the current instance:

```
class Customer {
    private static int lastID = 0;
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int[] accounts { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public int balance { get { return 100; } }
    public double interest { get { return this.balance * 1.05; } }

    Customer(string name, int[] accounts) {
        this.ID = lastID++;
        this.accounts = accounts;
        this.balance = 100;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Which allows you to restrict setting the `ID` outside your class.

The same also applies for all the other properties, as they are properties of every instance, not of the class itself. So change the `static` for all, `name`, `accounts`, `id`, `balance` and `interest`.

Finally select the customer with `ID` equal to 53 and set his/her name appropriately:

```
var customer in allCustomers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 53));
if (customer != null)
{
    customer.Name = "newName";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Customer` fields are `static`, which means their values are shared among all `Customer` instances.

You need to make them instance members:

```
class Customer
{
    public static int lastId = 0; // store the last id generated in this static variable

    // These fields are part of each customer, so they should not be static
    public string name;
    public int[] accounts = { };
    public int id = 0;
    public int balance = 100;
    public double interest = balance * 1.05;
    /* ... */

    public Customer()
    {
       name = "Person";
       balance = 100;
       id = ++lastId; // increment the last generated id and assign 
                      // this instance's id to it
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you are creating 99 instances (not 100), but are not storing them anywhere.

Try something like:

```
var customerList = new List<Customer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
   Customer newPerson = new Customer();
   customerList.Add(newPerson);
}
// Find the customer in the list with id 53
var customer53 = customerList.First(x => x.id == 53);
// Change its name
customer53.name = "John Doe";
// And print it
customer53.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

first off you will want to make the members of the class non-static, as currently if you change the name, they will all change. Then you want to store each of the instances into a `List<Customer>` which you can use from the `using System.Collections.Generic` library.

Then, with `using System.Linq` you can do

```
var customer53 = myCustomers.FirstOrDefault((x) => x.id == 53);
if (customer53 != null)
    customer53.name = "bob";
```

I recommend looking more into Linq if you choose this option